# OpenMPI error MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated

Tags: c, bash, openmpi

I need a c function for the matrix product with openMPI to collect the time for create a scalability plot. This is the c function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

void multimatrix(float *,float *, float*, int, int,int);

void multimatrix(float *A, float *B, float *C, int A_rows, int A_cols, int B_cols) {
    int i,j,k;
    for (i = 0; i < A_rows; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < B_cols; j++) {
            *(C+i*B_cols+j)=0;
            for(k=0;k<A_cols;k++){
                *(C+i*B_cols+j)+=*(A+i*A_cols+k)**(B+k*B_cols+j);
            }
        }
    }
}



void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // define the matrix
    int ROWS_A=25,COLS_A=25,COLS_B=25;
    int i,j;
    float *A=(float *)malloc(sizeof(float)*COLS_A*ROWS_A);
    float *B=(float *)malloc(sizeof(float)*COLS_B*COLS_A);
    float *C=(float *)malloc(sizeof(float)*COLS_B*ROWS_A);
    for(i=0;i<ROWS_A;i++){
        for(j=0;j<COLS_A;j++){
            *(A+i*COLS_A+j)=5-(i*(j+1));
        }   
    }
    for(i=0;i<COLS_A;i++){
        for(j=0;j<COLS_B;j++){
            *(B+i*COLS_B+j)=5+(i*(j-1));
        }  
    }

    // initialating OpenMPI
    int num_processor, my_id;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_processor);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_id);

    // define the numbers of rows for processor
    int rows_per_process = ROWS_A / num_processor;
    int rows_remaining = ROWS_A % num_processor;
    if(rows_remaining>my_id){
        rows_per_process += 1;
    }
    

    // create the allocation for the submatrix
    float *local_A = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * COLS_A * rows_per_process);
    float *local_C = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * COLS_B * rows_per_process);
    // start the threads process for the function multimatrix and collect the time
    double *time=(double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*num_processor);
    for(i=0;i<num_processor;i++){
        *(time+i)=0;
    }
    double time_value=0.0;
    MPI_Scatter(A, COLS_A * rows_per_process, MPI_FLOAT, local_A, COLS_A * rows_per_process, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(B, COLS_A * COLS_B, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Scatter(time, 1, MPI_DOUBLE,&time_value,1,MPI_DOUBLE,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    time_value = MPI_Wtime();
    multimatrix(local_A, B, local_C, rows_per_process, COLS_A, COLS_B);
    time_value = MPI_Wtime() - time_value;
    MPI_Gather(&time_value, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, time, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


    // conclude the threads process and unify the submatix of C
    MPI_Gather(local_C, COLS_B * rows_per_process, MPI_FLOAT, C, COLS_B * rows_per_process, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


    // free the submatrix used in the threads process and finalize the OpenMPI process
    free(local_A);
    free(local_C);
    free(A);
    free(B);
    free(C);
    MPI_Finalize();
    // find the minimum time of processing among the collected time values
    if(my_id==0){
        time_value=*(time+0);
        for(i=1;i<num_processor;i++){
            if(time_value>*(time+i)){
                time_value=*(time+i);
            }
        }
        printf("%.7f",time_value);
    }  
}
```

For automate the change of the numbers of the process I wrote a function in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash


rm -f timecollection.txt 
touch timecollection.txt

export UCX_NET_DEVICES=mlx5_0:1
export UCX_IB_GPU_DIRECT_RDMA=yes
export UCX_TLS=ib

echo "Compile program"
mpicc -o exam exam.c
echo

for parallel in {2..10}; do
    echo "Execute program - Parallel: $parallel"
    srun -N $parallel -p parallel --reservation=maintenance ./exam >> output.txt
    echo "$parallel     $(cat output.txt)" >> timecollection.txt
    echo "">>timecollection.txt
    rm output.txt
    echo
done

nano timecollection.txt

echo "Clear temporary file"
rm exam
echo
```

But i have a error from the terminal:

```
Execute program - Parallel: 2
[ibiscohpc-wn02:393110] *** An error occurred in MPI_Scatter
[ibiscohpc-wn02:393110] *** reported by process [139944564957224,1]
[ibiscohpc-wn02:393110] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[ibiscohpc-wn02:393110] *** MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated
[ibiscohpc-wn02:393110] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
[ibiscohpc-wn02:393110] ***    and potentially your MPI job)
srun: Job step aborted: Waiting up to 32 seconds for job step to finish.
slurmstepd: error: *** STEP 166080.0 ON ibiscohpc-wn01 CANCELLED AT 2023-06-09T17:15:31 ***
srun: error: ibiscohpc-wn02: task 1: Exited with exit code 15
srun: error: ibiscohpc-wn01: task 0: Killed
```

So the problem is about to `MPI_Scatter(A, COLS_A * rows_per_process, MPI_FLOAT, local_A, COLS_A * rows_per_process, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);`, but there is only when the variable `my_id` is equal to 0. So i wrong to write a part of the code in `MPI_Scatter`, but i don't understand where i wrong. Can anyone help me?

I try to controll if the sum of the variables `rows_per_process`, at the end of the thread process was equal to the number of the A's rows, but in each step of bash code, the of the `rows_per_process` was always lower of A's rows.
For example, when the numbers of process was equal to 2 `sum_rows_per_process=12`, but `ROWS_A=25`,
for `num_processor=3`, `sum_rows_per_process=16` and `ROWS_A=25`. And so on, in pratice the errors was always when `my_id=0`.